# Bat and Com, file. Init Error trying to start a exe file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am trying to run a exe from a Bat file.
The error is a popup **Init Error Genre Unknown.**
The game runs fine by it's self. But want to use a bat file./
What causes this? I have spent 3 days and nothing about a Init error Genre Unknown
on Google yahoo Dogpile or even webferret
I did check all the registry sites to make sure my settings are correct for Bat files.

```
    @echo off
    START "" "C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe" "-i"
    rem start /wait C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe
    pause
    if not errorlevel 0 goto :ERR1
    goto :STEP2
    :STEP2

    START "" "..\2atop\2atop.exe" "-i"
    rem start /wait C:\01Game\2atop\2atop.exe
    pause
    if not errorlevel 0 goto :ERR2
    goto :ALLOK
   :ERR1
    echo **** Warning: file1 did not work properly! ****
    echo.
    echo Press any key to terminate job ...
    pause>nul
    goto :END
    :ERR2
    echo **** Warning: file2 did not work properly! ****
    echo.
    echo Press any key to terminate job ...
    pause>nul
    goto :END
   :ALLOK
    echo ****** Job completed successfully *****
    echo.
    goto :END
    :END
    EXIT /B
```

Comment: What is that "-i". It is a parameter for your programs or a parameter for the START command?

Comment: When you say that the game runs fine by itself, what does it mean? How do you invoke the executable without your batch file, directly or using a shortcut (`.lnk`) file? As a wild guess, try removing double quotes around `"-i"`.

Comment: Andriy M, I was told "-i". – is how to open a bat file and not have the command window open.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you only need `CD` to the workung directory in your case.

```
cd /d C:\01Game\1aedit\files\audio
start /wait C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe
```

Btw. I can't see a reason for `start /wait`, `C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe` should also work without it.

Comment: Well I need 14 files to run each with a seperate folder, and each folder with 14 other folders Like this, C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe then the subfolders C:\01Game\1aedit\Files C:\01Game\1aedit\Files\audiobank

Comment: Well I need 14 files to run each with a seperate folder, and each folder with 14 other folders Like this, C:\01Game\1aedit\1aedit.exe then the subfolders C:\01Game\1aedit\Files C:\01Game\1aedit\Files\audiobank C:\01Game\1aedit\Files\textures C:\01Game\1aedit\Files\mesh C:\01Game\1aedit\Files\script anb so on, they are games and each needs to access it's own files. So i need to tell the bat file where each games working directory is at. and run the games in a loop one after the other as each level is completed. many thanks